# Javascript Array Problem

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why is JavaScript returning the wrong array length?

```
var myarray = ['0','1'];
delete myarray[0];
alert(myarray.length); //gives you 2
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The "delete" doesn't modify the array, but the elements *in* the array:

```
 # x = [0,1];
 # delete x[0]
 # x
 [undefined, 1]
```

What you need is [array.splice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)

Answer (score 5):

you have to use array.splice - see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

```
myarray.splice(0, 1);
```

this will then remove the first element

Comment: yes. The other code removes the item also. But it doesn't update the length.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/delete_Operator) the delete operator does not change the length ofth earray. You may use splice() for that.

Answer (score 1):

From Array's MDC documentation:

> "When you delete an array element, the
>   array length is not affected. For
>   example, if you delete a[3], a[4] is
>   still a[4] and a[3] is undefined. This
>   holds even if you delete the last
>   element of the array (delete
>   a[a.length-1])."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/delete_Operator

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-array-remove/)'s nice remove() method:

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(from, to) {
  var rest = this.slice((to || from) + 1 || this.length);
  this.length = from < 0 ? this.length + from : from;
  return this.push.apply(this, rest);
};
```

than

```
// Remove the second item from the array
array.remove(1);
// Remove the second-to-last item from the array
array.remove(-2);
// Remove the second and third items from the array
array.remove(1,2);
// Remove the last and second-to-last items from the array
array.remove(-2,-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the normal behavior. The delete() function does not delete the index, only the content of the index. So you still have 2 elements in the array, but at index 0 you will have `undefined`.